# Error GROUP BY in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

This is my query response.

```
id_project   filename
25           daf5c857-b4f3-4977-b2b7-fe61903cbc1f_3.jpg        
26           4452ff57-966b-49ec-9b90-ea8a78a7dad0_1.jpg        
26           4668ba37-8fea-48c8-955b-c6d71a8973dc_2.jpg        
26           9ee0f078-16db-4e4a-895b-54ab307b1fa6_3.jpg
```

I want to show one 26 field. I used this select code :

```
SELECT id_project, filename 
FROM image 
GROUP BY id_project
```

but show this error

> Msg 8120, Level 16, State 1, Line 2
>   Column 'image.filename' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

I use this code for solve but it shows the same result set as the original query.

```
select distinct id_project, filename 
from image
```

Comment: What is your end goal with the sql?

Comment: Your error is incredibly straight forward.

Comment: response write on first question

Comment: You say "I want to show one 26 field". So which `filename` do you want shown? What do the desired results look like?

Comment: That doesn't answer any of the above questions.

Comment: does not matter.only show one of 26

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To just show one row per `id_project` and one of the matching `filename` you need to wrap it in an aggregate.

You say it "does not matter.only show one of 26". This will return the alphabetically latest one.

```
SELECT id_project,
       MAX(filename) AS filename
FROM   image
GROUP  BY id_project
```

Or you can rewrite to get the [`ANY` aggregate](http://sqlblog.com/blogs/paul_white/archive/2011/07/02/undocumented-query-plans-the-any-aggregate.aspx)

```
WITH T
     AS (SELECT *,
                ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY id_project 
                                       ORDER BY id_project) AS RN
         FROM   image)
SELECT id_project,
       filename
FROM   T
WHERE  RN = 1
```